# Register webscript in alfresco 5

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I'd like to register a custom webscript in a alfresco 5 installation. To get a grip on the matter i started with this turorial: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/ws-config.html

It basically says: Login as admin, go to `Data Dictionary > Web Scripts Extensions > org > example`, place some xml files plus a .ftl file for presentation. In the end it directs one to `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index` and perfom a `Refresh Web Scripts.`

The result of this always is:

```
Maintenance Completed
Reset Web Scripts Registry; registered 505 Web Scripts. Previously, there were 505.
```

And no trace of my fancy hello world script.

I also tried to manually place the files in `/var/lib/tomcat7/shared/classes/alfresco/extension`. Also a restart of tomcat lead to no different result (did you try to turn it on and off again...).

It really frustrating as the documentation seems to be simple enough.

---

### What i tried also in detail

Taken from (Alfresco Developer: Intro to the Web Script Framework by Jeff Potts)

Navigate to /Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions

Create a file called **helloworld.get.desc.xml** with the following content:

```
<webscript>
    <shortname>Hello World</shortname>
    <description>Hello world web script</description>
    <url>/helloworld?name={nameArgument}</url>
</webscript>
```

Create a file called **helloworld.get.html.ftl** with the following content:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, ${args.name}!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

... Do refresh Web scripts.

As you can see this is a pretty tough implementation ... But even it's that simple it just is not working. Where could I possible have turned wrong?

Any heads up is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 approach using which we can deploy webscript in alfresco.

1.Placing webscript inside DataDictionary 
2.Placing webscript inside extension folder
In case of your code you are placing files in wrong folder.Below are correct location for each deployment approach.

Location for Data Dictionary

```
/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts/org/alfresco
```

Location for extension

```
tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback :). I had already tried to move the files to `tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts` and also `tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts\com\company`. Both scripts are not found. Also tried the first option yesterday with the same result. Maybe my files are flawed somehow. But they seem to contain the minimum content possible. Is there a config to enable webscripts or something i could have missed?

Comment: Ok... I just did everything again and copied 1:1 the content of my question and moved the files to `tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts\com\company`. Now it is working and i don't know why it did not work before. Thank you very much for your reply again :) If anyone is stumbeling in this quesion searching for help: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ws-presentation-locations.html this was were i initially found info about the file location.